# how to set only one key for stop/start setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function for stop and start the setInterval with key .
it's starts with S key and stops with Z key .

```
var refreshIntervalId;
window.addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDown,true);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

    function keyDown() {
        var e = window.event;
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 83:
                start();
                break;
            case 90:
                stop();
                break;
        }
    }

    function start() {
        stop();
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function() {
            // code...
        },10);
    }

    function stop() {
        if (refreshIntervalId != null) {
            clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
            refreshIntervalId = null;
        }
    }
```

So how can i set only Z key for start and stop the SetInterval ??
for example i press Z key and it starts then i press Z key again and it stops !
anyone can help me ?

Comment: Your first `addEventListener()` call is incorrect and won't do anything because there is no `"onkeydown"` event.  In your `keydown` function, instead of `var e = window.event`, you can just set an argument for the function (which will be the event object when the function is triggered), like this: `function keydown(e){ ...`

Comment: it works correctly !

Comment: It works because your second `addEventListener()` is written correctly, but the first one is doing nothing for you.  There is no `onkeydown` event, so that line will not register anything. It also works because you ARE getting a reference to the event, but you don't need to do it that old way. You can just add an `e` argument to the `keydown` function and remove the line about `var e...`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener and scroll to the `"Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent"` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code like below,

```
function keyDown() {
 var e = window.event;
 switch (e.keyCode) {
   case 90:
   if(refreshIntervalId) { 
      stop(); 
   } 
   else { 
      start(); 
   }
   break;
 }
}
```

Check if `refreshIntervalId` is a truthy value. If it is then stop the interval else start it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var boolStart = false;


    function keyDown() {
        var e = window.event;
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 83:
                if(!boolStart){
                    start();    
                }else{
                    stop();
                }

                break; 
        }
    }

    function start() {
        stop();
        boolStart = true;
        ..
    }

    function stop() {

        boolStart = false;
       ....        
    }
```

EDIT 1:

You can do in this way also.

```
var boolStart = false;

        function keyDown() {
            var e = window.event;
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 83:
                //;
                    boolStart = !boolStart;
                    if (!boolStart) {
                        start();
                    } else {
                        stop();
                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Please check EDIT1

Comment: I have a problem with this code in firefox browser. when i put this code in firefox console it says : _TypeError: e is undefined_ how can i fix this error  ?